# JFrame displays content only after resizing (Xuggler)

Tags: java, swing, xuggler

I Have written a listener for an IMediaReader from Xuggler.
It should show a video in a JPanel what i can add to a JFrame.

I have created this JFrame in the class main:

```
class Window extends JFrame {

    static IMediaReader reader;
    static Window main;

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("C:/Users/André/Desktop/Detail.wmv");
                reader.addListener(new Player(IMediaViewer.Mode.AUDIO_VIDEO, main));

                while (reader.readPacket() == null)
                    do {} while(false);  
            }
        }.start();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main = new Window();
            }
        });
    }

    private Window() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setVisible(true);
                setSize(700, 700);
            }
        });


    }

    // invoked by Player with the video panel 
    public void add(final JPanel videoPanel) {

        add(videoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
    }
}
```

It shows the video but it only works when i resize the window manually and that is my problem. Else, it shows a small black square.

Using pack() instead of setSize() or invoke repaint doesn't help.

The Code of class Player isn't just from me. I've just changed some things:

```
public class Player extends MediaListenerAdapter implements IMediaListener, IMediaViewer {

    private static Main main;

    Player(Mode mode, Main main) {
        setMode(mode);
        Player.main = main;
    }


        @Override
        public void onAddStream(IAddStreamEvent event)
        {
                [...]
            MediaFrame frame = new MediaFrame(stream, this, main);
                [...]
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event)
        {

            MediaFrame frame = mFrames.get(event.getStreamIndex());
                frame.setVideoImage(event.getPicture(), event.getImage());
        }

        static class PositionFrame extends JPanel
        {

            public PositionFrame(Player viewer, Main main)
            {
                main.add(this);



                mFrames.add(this);


            }



            protected void adjustSize()
            {
                invalidate();
            }


        }



        private class MediaFrame extends PositionFrame
        {

            // the video image

            private BufferedImage mImage;

            // the video panel

            private final JPanel mVideoPanel;

            // the stream

            private final IStream mStream;

            // the index of the stream (incase it's closed)

            private final int mStreamIndex;

            /**
             * Construct a media frame.
             * 
             * @param defaultCloseOperation what should Swing do if the window
             *              is closed. See the {@link javax.swing.WindowConstants}
             *              documentation for valid values.
             * @param stream the stream which will appear in this frame
             * @param viewer containing media viewer
             */

            public MediaFrame(IStream stream, 
                Player viewer, Main main)
            {
                super(viewer, main);

                // get stream and set title based it, establish a copy of the
                // stream since it lives in a separate thread

                mStream = stream.copyReference();
                mStreamIndex = mStream.getIndex();

                // the panel which shows the video image

                mVideoPanel = new JPanel()
                {


                    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                    {
                        paintPanel((Graphics2D) graphics);
                    }
                };

                // add the videoPanel

                add(mVideoPanel);

                // show the frame

                setVisible(true);
            }


            // set the video image

            protected void setVideoImage(IVideoPicture picture, BufferedImage image)
            {
                       [...]
                    }

            protected void paintPanel(Graphics2D graphics)
            {
                if (mImage != null)
                    graphics.drawImage(mImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }

}
```

It is made up from the class MediaViewer
http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/MediaViewer.java?r=644

EDIT: If I do it like this, it doesn't work without resizing manually.
I'm not shure if I have unterstood you right.

Comment: tried calling `repaint()` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code in two places.

```
 pack();
 setSize(700, 700);
```

The pack() class is wasteful since you are setting the size immediately afterwards.  Also, the first time you call in your constructor you haven't even added anything yet.

Try setting the size or calling pack after you have added the video component and after you have made the frame visible.

Based on your edits, I believe the issue is that you are setting the frame visible before the component is in place.  Move your setVisible and pack() calls to the end of your constructor for the `Main` class instead of the `add()` method.

Based on more edits to your question:  As I mentioned in the comments, make sure you separate off the GUI code in a separate call to invokeLater to get things happening on the EDT.  Therefore you need to move your IMediaReader creation and thread starting into your main() method, then after that create a new call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater that creates a new Main, class.     By the way, Main is a confusing name for a class.

Comment: If I do it like this:

Comment: class Main extends JFrame {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Main();
 }
 IMediaReader reader;

 private Main() {

 setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("C:/Users/André/Desktop/Detail.wmv");
  reader.addListener(new Player(IMediaViewer.Mode.AUDIO_VIDEO, this));
    
  while (reader.readPacket() == null)
   do {} while(false);  
 }
 
 // invoked by Player with the video panel 
 public void add(JPanel videoPanel) {
  add(videoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  pack();
  setVisible(true); 
 }
}

It doesn't work, too.

Comment: That is still calling pack BEFORE setVisible.  Flip them.

Comment: That doesn't work, too. I see just the black square.
Nevertheless, thank you for your help

Comment: Try starting this on the EDT with a call to 'SwingUtilities.invokeLater'

Comment: Do you know which method is called when I resize the window manually?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it.
I've edited my question with the new code but I think I haven't done it right

Comment: You are close but your setVisible and Pack need to be inside the runnable as well. Not just the addition to the panel.  Speaking of which, where is the add() method called from and when is the constructor for Main() called other than in the main() method?

Comment: The add() method is called from a subclass PositionFrame of the class Player. The cunstructor for Main() is just called in the main() method.
I will post the code of class Player but it is a bit messy.
It doesn't help to do setVisible() and pack() inside the runnable.

Comment: Still isn't a SSCCE but you are a step closer.  What creates a Player class?

Comment: This line in the constructor of Main:
reader.addListener(new Player(IMediaViewer.Mode.AUDIO_VIDEO, this));

Comment: If I do it like this, it doesn't work without resizing manually. I'm not shure if I have unterstood you right.